# Vim: interactively check what's happening before substitute?

Tags: vim

`vim` has very powerful command tools. I can substitute 'Set's for all 'Array's:

```
:%s/Array/Set/g
```

But can I do this interactively as Unix commands(e.g. `rm`)? I hope `vim` to ask me whether I really want to replace a word, rather than substitute them all at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by appending another command as:

```
:%s/Array/Set/gc
```